# NU1107 - Xamarin Android erro when updating nuget packages

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been trying to update an XF solution.  I've read a bunch of posts on this.  Basically, the suggestion seems to be to update packages in an order.  I've been gotten rid of all of my Xamarin.Android.Support.* libraries.  I've gotten rid of my Xamarin Essentials.  Basically, I've gotten rid of everything in my nuget references.  I'm lost on what to do now.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils. Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils 27.0.2.1 directly to project GolferAdmin.Android to resolve this issue. 
 GolferAdmin.Android -> GolferAdmin -> Xamarin.Essentials 1.0.0 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils (>= 27.0.2.1) 
 GolferAdmin.Android -> Xamarin.Forms 3.4.0.1008975 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 27.0.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils (= 27.0.2).  GolferAdmin.Android C:\Users\theev\Dropbox\Projects\GolfMobileUserAdmin\GolferAdmin\GolferAdmin\GolferAdmin.Android\GolferAdmin.Android.csproj  1

Just to update this, I also got this exact same problem with a frest xf project that has just been created.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally got the updated packages to install.  I've read redth's blog post on this.  That was still no help.  I finally had to uninstall everyone of the android support library nuget packages, reinstall them, and reboot.  I think this reboot is actually a big deal.  As I remember reading, VS keeps things in memory, and it had an in memory image of the older components that were creating a conflict.  By rebooting, everything was flushed.  I forgot that I have had this problem before.  anyway, I think that was the solution.

Hopefully some of this helps.